# Is there way to avoid expanding side pane when creating it?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

Below is the code creating side pane but expanding and collapsing side pane. Need to avoid expanding side pane when creating it.

```
Xrm.App.sidePanes.createPane({
    title: "Reservation: Ammar Peterson",
    imageSrc: "WebResources/sample_reservation_icon",
    hideHeader: true,
    canClose: true,
    width: 600
}).then((pane) => {
    pane.navigate({
        pageType: "entityrecord",
        entityName: "sample_reservation",
        entityId: "d4034340-4623-e811-a847-000d3a30c619",
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid expanding side pane when creating it. use "hidden" property in options and also in callback function. See example code below

```
Xrm.App.sidePanes.createPane({
    title: "Reservation: Ammar Peterson",
    imageSrc: "WebResources/sample_reservation_icon",
    hideHeader: true,
    canClose: true,
    width: 600,
    hidden: true
}).then((pane) => {
    pane.navigate({
        pageType: "entityrecord",
        entityName: "sample_reservation",
        entityId: "d4034340-4623-e811-a847-000d3a30c619",
    });
    pane.hidden = false;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's all about reading the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-app/xrm-app-sidepanes/createpane